# How do I join a Lync/Skype for business online meeting without a microphone?

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, lync, lync-2013

The meeting is a presentation rather than a conference call and therefore no microphone is needed to provide feedback. Joining the call results in a Lync/Skype For Business error that there is no valid recording device and asks me to setup an audio device. There is an option to retry or to call a number but I want to listen through my computer using my headphones, not my phone.

I have read that this appears to be a bug that has been around since at least 2010 but does not seem to be addressed. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Edit:

In response to suggestion that workaround might be OS specific...

Lync 2013 (15.0.4727.1001) / Skype for business 2015

Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: In my experience, it's not possible. You can only join a call if you have a microphone, even if you just want to listen.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**:
You can use some virtual audio device, like [this one](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/).
After installing it, you will see a new recording device in Control Panel (mmsys.cpl) and Lync will allow you to join the audio call.

**Method 2**:
According to this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/11/2014/09/23/lync-2013-explained-no-audio-detected/), you can trick Lync/S4B without installing any software but you still need admin rights to edit registry:

1. Insert your headphones into microphone plug for 10-15 seconds to initialize it (the microphone) in drivers.
2. Open regedit.exe and proceed to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture**.
3. Find the subkey with DeviceState = 0x00000008 and change it into 0x00000001.
4. Check for a new recording device using "control mmsys.cpl,,1", start Lync and join the audio call.

**Method 3**:
If you don't have admin rights, just put some old headphones into the mic plug.

Comment: This works, but the audio quality will be terribad. Desk/headset mics are cheap nowadays.

Comment: You right but it's not an issue if don't plan to speak through this "microphone" and just want to hear the others.